# Removing strings after a certain character in a given text

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a dataset like the one below. I would like to remove all characters after the character ©. How can I do that in R?

```
data_clean_phrase <- c("Copyright © The Society of Geomagnetism and Earth", 
"© 2013 Chinese National Committee ")

data_clean_df <- as.data.frame(data_clean_phrase)
```

Comment: Is it after a specific character, or after a specific index?

Comment: After a specific character: ©

Comment: Then, seems like the existing answer solved your question  :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For instance:

```
 rs<-c("copyright @ The Society of mo","I want you to meet me @ the coffeshop")
 s<-gsub("@.*","",rs)
 s
 [1] "copyright "             "I want you to meet me "
```

Or, if you want to keep the @ character:

```
 s<-gsub("(@).*","\\1",rs)
 s
 [1] "copyright @"             "I want you to meet me @"
```

EDIT: If what you want is to remove everything from the last @ on you just have to follow this previous example with the appropriate regex. Example:

```
rs<-c("copyright @ The Society of mo located @ my house","I want you to meet me @ the coffeshop")
s<-gsub("(.*)@.*","\\1",rs)
s
[1] "copyright @ The Society of mo located " "I want you to meet me "
```

Given the matching we are looking for, both sub and gsub will give you the same answer.

Comment: Thank you. and What if I want to do it for the last © in the text. Consider this: c(" © aaa © bbb") --> c( "© aaa")

Comment: @HamidehIraj  You can make use of [regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449564/regex-return-all-before-the-second-occurrence) for executing that.

Comment: You are welcome. Once you get use to regex you'll see that it is as easy to remove from the last @ char. I've edited my answer to include this case as well.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness: You could use the stringr package to extract what you want.

```
library(stringr)
data_clean_phrase <- c("Copyright © The Society of Geomagnetism and Earth", 
                       "© 2013 Chinese National Committee ")

str_extract(data_clean_phrase, "^(.*?©)") # including the @
str_extract(data_clean_phrase, "^.*(?=(©))") # excluding the @
```

Note: I chose to `str_extract`, you could also choose to `str_remove`.