# Removing strings after $ in a tibble

Tags: r

Say I have a tibble that looks like this

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(`var` = c(1,2), `text` = c("elephant $ more text", "cat $ some more text"))
```

and I would like to programmatically get all the text from the character $ to be removed, so to obtain the equivalent result of

```
df <- tibble(`var` = c(1,2), `text` = c("elephant ", "cat "))
```

I tried to use the equivalent of [Removing strings after a certain character in a given text](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/8922/removing-strings-after-a-certain-character-in-a-given-text?newreg=c0715d0aa4d944d0b6d8ec6d03908aab)

but it seems that thee special character $ does not yield the desired outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by simply escaping the $ character using the `\\` characters:

```
df %>%
  mutate(text = gsub("\\\$.*", "", text))
```

| var | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | elephant more text |
| 2 | cat some more text |

Comment: Thank you, almost what I needed, but replacing "\\\$" with "\\$.*" works

Comment: You're completely right, looked over the 'after' bit and thought you just wanted to remove the '$' character.